# How to extend styling of component without using wrapper element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, atomic-design

I'm working with `styled-components` in [atomic system](https://atomicdesign.bradfrost.com/chapter-2/).
I have my `<Atom title={title} onClick={onClick}/>`
And I have molecule that extends that atom, by just adding some functionality to it without wrapping element:

```
const Molecule = ({}) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('Base title')

  const onClick = () => {
    // some actions
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    setTitle('New title')
  },[conditions changed])

  return(
    <Atom title={title} onClick={onClick}/>
  )
}
```

I have base styling in `<Atom/>` but I would like to add some more to it in `<Molecule/>`. Is it possible to do it without creating extra wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but the question is if it's worthy the effort - the most anticipated way would be to do it as the documentation says - to wrap the *styled component* and extend the styles (but this is what you want to avoid). So either:

- you could assign a `className` to `Atom`, so you can adjust/overwrite the styles with CSS
- pass the `extraStyles` props to `Atom` and then pass to the *styled component* and just use inside after the previous, default styles to overwrite them
- or either pass some `extraStyles` as `CSSProperties` object and just use them as *inline* styling.

https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-leftpad-znip6b?file=/src/App.js:64-545

```
/* styles.css */
.extraClass {
  color: green;
}

const AtomStyled = styled.div`
  font-size: 17px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 600;
`;

const Atom = ({ children, className, extraStyles }) => {
  return (
    <AtomStyled style={extraStyles} className={className}>
      {children}
    </AtomStyled>
  );
};

const Molecule = () => {
  return (
    <Atom className={'extraClass'} extraStyles={{ fontSize: 27 }}>
      Atom
    </Atom>
  );
};
```